# A problem to get data from store in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm creating to do list app so I created API using laravel and it works fine . The scenario is when user login I dispatch an action to check his email and password then update the store in redux with the user tasks . The tasks reach to the reducer fine but I cannot get it in the TasksComponent I get undefined when console.log(this.props.tasks)  or even console.log(this.props.isLoading)
**The reducer login**

```js
import * as ActionTypes from './ActionTypes';

export const Login = (state = {
    tasks: [],
    categories: [],
    error: null,
    isLoading: true
}, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.AUTH_LOADING:
            return {...state, tasks:[], categories:[], error: null, isLoading: true}
            case ActionTypes.AUTH_SUCCESS: 
            console.log(action.payload.user.tasks)
             return {...state, tasks: action.payload.user.tasks, categories: action.payload.user.categories,error: null, isLoading: false}
        case ActionTypes.AUTH_FAIL: 
             return {...state, tasks:[], categories:[], error: action.error, isLoading: false}
        default: 
            return state;
    }

}
```

**The Action creator**

```js
import * as ActionTypes from './ActionTypes';
import { baseUrl } from '../shared/baseUrl';

export const authSuccess = (authData) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.AUTH_SUCCESS,
    payload: authData
});

export const authFail = (error) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.AUTH_FAIL,
    error: error
});

export const authLoading = () =>({
    type: ActionTypes.AUTH_LOADING
})

export const auth = (email, password) => dispatch => {
    dispatch(authLoading());

    const user = {
        email: email,
        password: password
    }

    return fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/users/login',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
    })
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(user => {
        dispatch(authSuccess(user));
    })
    .catch(error => dispatch(authFail(error)));
}
```

**The tasks component**

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Loading } from './LoadingComponent';

class Tasks extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    render() {
        if(this.props.isLoading) {
            <Loading />
        } else {
            return(<h1>Yes</h1>)
        }
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return {
        isLoading: state.isLoading // Always get undefined
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Tasks);
```

Comment: What is state in your mapStateToProps function: `console.log('state is:',JSON.stringify(state,undefined,2))` You could also check redux devtools to see what the state is.

Comment: I found that I supposed to add in mapStateToProps the reducer what I mean is isLoading : state.login.isLoading ===> now its working but why?? I didn't do it before and was working what's new ????